# Get group of objects filtered from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Name"];
[dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Last"];
[dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Phone1"];
[dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Phone2"];
[dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Phone3"];
[dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Address"];
```

What is the best way to pull out only the phone numbers?

(this is a dynamic dictionary, sometimes 2 phone numbers and sometimes 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't set Phone numbers under different keys (Because language gives you array).

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];

dic[@"Name"] = @"1";
dic[@"Last"] = @"1" ;
dic[@"Address"] = @"1";
dic[@"Phone"] = phoneNumbers;

[dic[@"Phone"] addObject:@"123"];
[dic[@"Phone"] addObject:@"213"];
[dic[@"Phone"] addObject:@"456"];

// Now retieve phone numbers
for (NSString *phoneNumber in dic[@"Phone"]) {
    NSLog(@"Number: %@", phoneNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
  NSSet* passingKeys = [dict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [key rangeOfString:@"Phone"].location != NSNotFound;
  }];
```